# What would cause delete to leave garbage values in data fields of my class?

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator, garbage

I have a node class that contains 3 node pointers and 2 integers. I allocate all the nodes with `new`, but when I call `delete` on them, the integers get set to `-17891602` and it's screwing up the rest of my code's boundary checking. What would cause `delete` to do that?

Comment: Can you share your code.

Comment: Without seeing some code it's hard to know. Maybe you have a bug in your destructor(s)?

Comment: Why are you checking the memory contents after you called `delete` on it? You are not supposed to do that.`delete` does not guarantee to write anything specific at memory locations.Many implementations of delete do intentionally write specific garbage to help detect mistakes like accessing the memory after calling `delete`.

Answer (score 5):

After a `delete` that memory is not yours any more. Don't inspect it, don't do anything with it, because if you do then you have Undefined Behavior. It will likely soon be reused.

Comment: Just to add, many compilers, in debug builds, will deliberately write garbage to freed memory to make it easier to catch you accessing stuff you shouldn't have.

Comment: It seems to me that yemathums is saying that deleting pointer members of a node changes the integer members. He is not inspecting deleted memory (as far as he knows).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the pointer fields also get new values. Are they equal to 0xfeeefeee? (That's -17891602 in hexadecimal.) Your memory manager might be overwriting freed memory so it's easier to recognize in crash dumps when you attempt to read or write memory you're not supposed to access anymore.

If you're reading freed objects to do bounds checking, then you're relying on undefined behavior. Check the documentation for your environment to find out what, if anything, it does with freed memory. Your bounds checker will need to co-operate with it; you cannot assume it will work in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop on Linux and use `gdb` you could put a watchpoint using the `watch` command to GDB. This can help finding when was a memory location overwritten.